# Does Opensea.io updates "%xx have this trait" when new tokens are added to the collection?

Tags: blockchain, nft, opensea, erc721

There is one section on Opensea.io web page that shows the percentage of other tokens in the collection that has the same trait. Such as "%xx have this trait"

When the collection creator add new tokens to the collection, this percentage will definitely change. But would Opensea automatically update this percentage? Or it stay the same at all time (so that the percentage is actually wrong)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official statement about this, that is why I wrote the support. My traits did not update automatically (filters). So they fixed it in the latest update.

The only thing I can think of is trying to refresh the metadata (detail view of a NFT): [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTSnZ.png)

If this does not work you have to write the support here: https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).